# Adding class attribute to osCommerce tep_image function

Tags: oscommerce

I'm trying to make my product image format a certain way using CSS, but I'm not sure where to add the following code to the `tep_image` function call:

```
class="single-product"
```

I want the generated image to have the extra class attribute included as part of its HTML.

I'm hoping I don't have to add an if statement to the constructor class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tep_image` function is located in [`\includes\functions\html_output.php`](https://github.com/osCommerce/oscommerce2/blob/master/catalog/includes/functions/html_output.php#L75).

```
tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $product_info['products_image'], 
          addslashes($product_info['products_name']), 
          SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT, 
          'class="single-product"')
```

Any extra attributes you need to add to the image function will be after setting the image dimensions, so place the CSS as the fifth parameter.