# Adding CSS class attribute to osCommerce tep_image

Tags: php, css, oscommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding class attribute to osCommerce tep_image function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494326/adding-class-attribute-to-oscommerce-tep-image-function)

I need to add an ID or a class to an image in osCommerce so that I can resize it using media queries.

I have tried adding `class="classname"` all over this statement but it always fails to work.

[A similar question on tep_image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494326/adding-class-attribute-to-oscommerce-tep-image-function) doesn't seem to fit due to the 'bts_select' in my case.

```
tep_image(bts_select(images, 'logo' . (ITS_CHRISTMAS == 'true' ? '-xmas' : '') . '.gif'), STORE_NAME) . '</a>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tep_image()](https://github.com/osCommerce/oscommerce2/blob/master/catalog/includes/functions/html_output.php#L75) function is not documented but the source code is fairly straightforward:

```
function tep_image($src, $alt = '', $width = '', $height = '', $parameters = '') {
    //[...]
    if (tep_not_null($parameters)) $image .= ' ' . $parameters;

    $image .= ' />';

    return $image;
}
```

The fifth parameter gets injected as-is right before the end tag. That's all you need.